# Can PHP handle "XML" with double namespaces per tag without regex?

Tags: php, xml

I have a file full of XML-like tags, consisting of `<is:namespace:tag ...>` arranged in a HTML/XML-like manner. These are used to generate and render HTML via creative use of the smarty library. Our template files no longer have any smarty in them, and I would like to write a rendering engine using PHP's built in XML/DOM libraries to parse the XML-like content. Sadly, the XML-like language that I have is not compatible with PHP's XML parsing libraries.

All examples use the same variable:

```
$template = '<is:namespace:tag attr="value">foo<is:namespace:tag attr="value" /></is:namespace:tag>';
```

Example (make sure that PHP warnings are on!):

```
$parser = simplexml_load_string($template);
$parser = XMLReader::xml($template);
while($parser->read()) { echo $parser->name; }
$parser = DOMDocument::loadXML($template);
$parser = new SimpleXMLElement($template);
```

Every method attempted throws warnings - of note that the `QName` (`is:namespace:tag` bit) is unparseable, due to violating the XML standard, which the tools were designed to respect.

I have also tried:

```
$parser = DOMDocument::loadHTML($template);
```

Which also complains about namespaces lacking declaration and tag names being invalid.

I recognize that if the contents of my XML have no value I can use `str_replace` or a regex to strip the `:`'s, but I would strongly prefer to refrain from data mangling.

How can I use PHP's built in XML or DOM libraries to parse this "improved" format?

Comment: You are violating XML and wonder, why a XML-parser can't read this? This is not a "improved format", but a broken standard. Breaking a standard is never a good idea, especially why do you use XML at all, if you don't want to respect it? What I want to say: Fix the problem and not the symptons ;)

Comment: @KingCrunch "improved" !== improved. I thought I made it clear why - just wish I could find a how. This is not what I would have chosen for a file format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If - apart from that colon - the rest of the XML is "valid", there is a high chance that you can simply fix this with a regular expression based search and replace.

The following line does replace the `is:namespace` part with the namespace prefix `ns1`:

```
$fixed = preg_replace('((</?)is:namespace(:[a-z]+))', '$1ns1$2', $template);
```

Before then loading this as XML document, the prefix needs to be defined in the XML documents root (also called document) element:

```
$fixed = "<root xmlns:ns1='is:namespace'>$fixed</root>";
```

It can then safely loaded as XML document in any of the libxml based parsers, e.g. SimpleXML:

```
$parser = simplexml_load_string($fixed);

echo $parser->asXML();
```

The output then is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root xmlns:ns1="is:namespace">
  <ns1:tag attr="value">
    foo
    <ns1:tag attr="value"/>
  </ns1:tag>
</root>
```

See as well [the online demo](http://eval.in/10046). If your data makes use of CDATA and the string `is:namespace:` is duplicated therein, there is a change that this will not safely work.

Comment: It sounds like your answer to the "without regex" part of the question is "no" :). In truth, the special string does have a very low probability of being duplicated inside of CDATA sections - little case for presenting it to the user, and CDATA is used mainly for inline CSS/JS support. I'll suggest this solution to the author of the file format.

Comment: As it's invalid XML, there exists no XML parser not complaining about it. That's why regex is used here. One could try an incremental parse approach going from each reported location to the next, but I guess just pre-processing with regex is more sane for the moment.